# How do I make Gson serialize private classes like java.nio.HeapByteBuffer in JDK17?

Tags: java, gson, java-17

I tried to create a custom ByteBufferTypeAdapter and registered it with the java.nio.ByteBuffer class.

But at runtime the class is actually the private java.nio.HeapByteBuffer so Gson does not find a TypeAdapter for it at all.

```
class ByteBufferTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<ByteBuffer>, JsonSerializer<ByteBuffer> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(ByteBuffer src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(src.array()));
    }

    @Override
    public ByteBuffer deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(json.getAsString());
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    }
}
```

```
private static Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(java.nio.ByteBuffer.class, new ByteBufferTypeAdapter())
            .registerTypeAdapter(Instant.class,
                    (JsonSerializer<Instant>) (src, typeOfSrc, context) -> new JsonPrimitive(src.toString()))
            .create();
```

Test

```
        ByteBuffer test = ByteBuffer.wrap("Hello".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        String asJson = gson.toJson(test);

does not use serialize method and produces: {"hb":[72,101,108,108,111],"offset":0,"isReadOnly":false,"bigEndian":true,"nativeByteOrder":false,"mark":-1,"position":0,"limit":5,"capacity":5,"address":0}
```

I then tried to register the same adapter with the HeapByteBuffer type but that class is private and I do not have access to the class of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GsonBuilder#registerTypeHierarchyAdatper(Class,Object)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.10.1/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object)) to register the type-adapter for a type *and* its subtypes. Here's its documentation from Gson 2.10.1:

> Configures Gson for custom serialization or deserialization for an inheritance type hierarchy. This method combines the registration of a `TypeAdapter`, `JsonSerializer` and a `JsonDeserializer`. If a type adapter was previously registered for the specified type hierarchy, it is overridden. If a type adapter is registered for a specific type in the type hierarchy, it will be invoked instead of the one registered for the type hierarchy.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `baseType` - the class definition for the type adapter being registered for the base class or interface
>
> `typeAdapter` - This object must implement at least one of `TypeAdapter`, `JsonSerializer` or `JsonDeserializer` interfaces.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> a reference to this `GsonBuilder` object to fulfill the "Builder" pattern
>
> **Since:**
>
> 1.7

---

## Example

Here's a working example where the adapter converts the `ByteBuffer` to and from Base64 strings.

### Source Code

**ByteBufferTypeAdapter.java**:

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

public class ByteBufferTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ByteBuffer> {

    /*
     * WARNING: This adapter does not store the following state of the ByteBuffer:
     * 
     *              * position
     *              * limit
     *              * capacity
     *              * read-only vs writable
     *              * direct vs non-direct
     *              * byte order
     *              * the mark value (there's no "get mark" method)
     * 
     *          As a consequence, the deserialized ByteBuffer may not match the
     *          originally serialized ByteBuffer exactly. The deserialized buffer
     *          will always have a position of 0, a limit equal to its capacity,
     *          and a capacity equal to the size of the decoded bytes. It will
     *          also always be a writable, non-direct buffer with a byte order
     *          of BIG_ENDIAN.
     * 
     *          Use 'beginObject()' / 'endObject()' if you want to serialize and 
     *          deserialize more or all of the buffer's state.
     */

    @Override
    public ByteBuffer read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(reader.nextString());
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, ByteBuffer data) throws IOException {
        if (data == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }

        /*
         * This approach avoids three things:
         * 
         *    1. Avoids trying to use the backing array directly via 'array()', as that
         *       method will throw an exception for direct buffers. Let the implementation
         *       of 'encode(ByteBuffer)' handle if there's a backing array or not.
         * 
         *    2. Calling 'data.duplicate()' means the state of 'data' is not modified by
         *       the call to 'encode'. The "duplication" is cheap since the bytes themselves
         *       are shared between the two instances.
         * 
         *    3. Only the bytes from the buffer's position to its limit are encoded, which
         *       avoids serializing unnecessary data. You could also call 'withoutPadding()'
         *       on the encoder to avoid more possibly unnecessary data.
         */
        ByteBuffer base64Bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(data.duplicate());
        String base64String = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.decode(base64Bytes).toString();
        writer.value(base64String);
    }
}
```

**Data.java**:

```java
package com.example:

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public record Data(String name, ByteBuffer buffer) {}
```

**Main.java**:

```java
package com.example;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Data original = new Data("Test", ByteBuffer.wrap("Hello, World!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        System.out.printf("Original data: %s%n", original);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(ByteBuffer.class, new ByteBufferTypeAdapter())
                .setPrettyPrinting() // make output easier to read for example
                .create();

        String jsonString = gson.toJson(original);
        System.out.printf("%nJSON string:%n%s%n%n", jsonString);

        Data decoded = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
        System.out.printf("Decoded data: %s%n", decoded);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Original data: Data[name=Test, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=13 cap=13]]

JSON string:
{
  "name": "Test",
  "buffer": "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ\u003d\u003d"
}

Decoded data: Data[name=Test, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=13 cap=13]]
```